# Problem with SFML installation connected with .exe file

Tags: c++, exe, sfml

I tried to install SFML by doing everything tutorial on the official site says. It is said, that after pasting the code (before dragging the .dll files from bin) the error should pop up about missing of the .dll file. I get an error, however it's a different one. It says that the compiler can't find .exe file. I couldn't find an .exe file of this project. It's not in Debug folder nor in Release folder. What do I do?

Here are the pictures of code and folders:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLjDD.png - code

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfRoH.png - folder

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLDVb.png - first debug folder (empty)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph5bq.png - folder

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUFQL.png - second debug folder (no .exe here)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcAQ3.png - error (It translates as: Unable to start the program, because .exe file is missing)

Comment: You are not getting your executable built (so there won't be an exe) because you are missing the library for sfml-window.

Comment: What should I do?